# ViewBag doesn't load

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm beginning to learn ASP.NET MVC 5, and I'm just trying to make random things to get myself familiar with the system. I tried executing the following code in a standard environment (more or less exactly what you get when you load of a new blank project), but some reason I can't pass a string to my ViewBag properly.

Controller

```
public ActionResult News(String date)
{
    ViewBag.Message = Server.HtmlEncode(date);
    return View();
}
```

View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "News";
}
<h2>News</h2>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Message</h1>
    <p class="lead">This is my new website. I hope that I learn to develop the appropriate skills to create it.</p>
</div>
```

Some reason it just doesn't show anything for the area where I designated the ViewBag message to go. What's up with it?

Also, as I curiosity question, I noticed some code where they use things like "class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg"" but I couldn't find anywhere that they actually defined the class. How does this work and where is the class declaration?

Thanks for your time!

EDIT: OK, my mistake was pretty stupid. I forgot that you need to pass ?date= when the variable isn't named id.

I see in the comments that the "btn" class is a CSS class not a C# one, but nonetheless, where would I go if I wanted to edit it and/or make my own similar classes?

Thanks again!

Comment: Are you passing a value to the date parameter? What happens if you ust hard code a value - e.g. ViewBag.Message = "some message"`?

Comment: And `class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg"` is a html class attribute for styling the element using css (in this case it used by bootstrap), not a c# class)

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that the date parameter your passing through is not been matched by the Action method.

Simply Debug you code and check the value of date before it is assigned to the Viewbag.

Also, you could show the code that calls the 'News' Action Result.